# pass 2 arguments to a partial view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

i have one main view and a partial view. i got 2 variables from the main view to controller but i don't know how to pass 2 variables to partial view. for one variable its working but for more than one its not working.

my code

controller

```
 public PartialViewResult cal(int id,string name)
    {

        List<string> details = new List<string>();
        details.Add(""+id);

        details.Add(name);

        return PartialView(details);
    }
```

partialview

```
 @{ 
  @model List<string>
  }

    <script>

        var empid,user;

        empid = parseInt(@Model[0]);
        user = @Model[1] //name not getting

        $(document).ready(function () {
          //code
         });
```

i tried some code from here but the name is not getting. i tried with class also  but both are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than creating a List to pass your values to the view model try to create a strongly typed view model representing exactly what you need in the view.  For example:

```
public class CalViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then in the controller:

```
var vm = new CalViewModel()
{
    Id = id,
    Name = name
};
return PartialView(vm);
```

And then in the view:

```
@model CalViewModel

<script>
    var empid,user;
    empid = parseInt(@Model.Id);
    user = '@Model.Name';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //code
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks its working.............